# MongoDB and .NET: Filter on specific field in child array using FilterDefinition

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a class which creates a list of filters from an input.
The filters are found by calling a function for each filter like this:

```
public void created_after(string date)
{
    DateTime convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    filters.Add(Builders<User>.Filter.Gte(x => x.Created, convertedDate));
}
```

Now i need to segment on a field on a child array on the user.
In this case, i just need to know if any alert has a Created value higher than a given date. 
My data looks like this:

```
{ 
    "DisplayName" : "PestisanRadu", 
    "Alerts" : [
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("577a26a12b365917c4d67dd5"), 
            "Created" : ISODate("2016-10-05T09:17:44.382+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "UserId" : ObjectId("577a26a82b365917c4d68009"), 
            "Created" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:44:45.743+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "Created" : ISODate("2016-10-05T09:17:43.423+0000")
}
```

For the class to work, i need to keep the FilterDefinition type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use other same method which take `FieldDefinition` as parameter, in your case would be

```
filters.Add(Builders<User>.Filter.Gt("Alerts.Created", convertedDate));
```

Note that the string `"Alerts.Created"` is `FieldDefinition`

Comment: Thank you, this works.
How come i dont have to specify that it only needs to have one alert which satisfy the criteria?